# If I cannot reference a class in another project due to circular dependencies, is it ok to just copy the class to the project?

Tags: c#, conventions, code-duplication

In some project A, I need to use a class that belongs to project B. However, I cannot reference the class because when I try to add a reference to project B, Visual Studio doesn't let me due to circular dependencies. I am wondering what the conventions are in situations like this (and I'm finding myself in these situations more and more).

Let's say the class in project B is called `Person`, and it has some properties like `Name`, `Age`, `Nationality`. Let's also say I need to use this `Person` class in Project A because there is some method in some class of project A that needs `Person`. So ideally I would just pass in `Person` as an argument to this method. Is it okay to just create another `Person` class in project A with the same properties, methods, etc? I want to avoid duplicating code whenever I can, but I feel like this is better than passing all the `Person` properties as arguments into the method in project A that may be needed (which would work since the properties are types like `string`, `int`, etc., but I feel like it's inelegant). Basically I'm wondering what the convention is for situations like this.

Comment: the conventional solution is to make a Project C that both A and B can reference, and move the common code into that.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm working with a large code base so it would feel silly to make a project just for this, but perhaps I can find an existing project that both reference and put it in an appropriate place there.

Comment: The two projects should have different namespaces which should eliminate the circular references.

Comment: I think some refactoring is needed there.Do you these 'Person' classes do the same thing? Maybe seperating them both into a combined namespace and into there own small class library. You could even create a nuget package for the library so it can be reused.